# YouTube Data API: Permission to video rating only

Tags: youtube-data-api

Is it possible to ask just for rating permission?

I do not want to administer YouTube videos or managing the account. Just rating videos?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the YouTube Data API does not have such fine grained endpoint permission scopes.

According to the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/rate), for an app to be allowed to programmatically apply a like/dislike rating or cancel a like/dislike rating, it has to have granted permission of operation by a YouTube account (that is channel) on the following scopes:

> [**Authorization**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/rate#auth)
>
> This request requires authorization with at least one of the following scopes ([read more about authentication and authorization](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication)).
>
> **Scope**
> `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner`
> `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube`
> `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl`

These are all the scopes the API defines for this endpoint. Among them there's no one that would let you do *only video rating*.